# Insertar código html de un fichero externo mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando ejecutar el contenido de un fichero html (`fichero2.html`) que se encuentra en una ruta diferente a la del fichero con el que estoy trabajando (`fichero1.html`). Para ser más específico supongamos que el `fichero1` tiene el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <!--El contenido del fichero 2 se debe ubicar aquí-->
        </div>

        <script>
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "Esto es un texto de prueba";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Deseo que dentro de la etiqueta `<div>` con el `id="contenedor"` se ubique una tabla que tengo en el `fichero2`, cuyo contenido es:

```
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Empresa</th>
          <th>Contacto</th>
          <th>País</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Claudio Bosoletti</td>
          <td>claudio@gmail.com</td>
          <td>Argentina</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Edgardo Fernandez</td>
          <td>edgardo@gmail.com</td>
          <td>España</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Lucia Guillamondegui</td>
          <td>lucia@gmail.com</td>
          <td>Uruguay</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

De que manera se puede "insertar" la tabla dentro del contenedor `<div>` mediante javascript? Este código que estoy ejemplificando es una simplificación del proyecto en el que estoy trabajando, pero para más conciso supongamos que el `fichero1` tiene la siguiente ruta: `proyecto/carpeta1/fichero1.html`
y el `fichero2` tiene la ruta: `proyecto/carpeta2/fichero2.html`

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Se podría saber por qué quieres hacerlo así? `fichero2` parece ser un documento HTML en sí, no una parte de otro fichero. ¿No es acaso una lógica errada? Por eso pregunto.

Comment: Si estaba mal redactado el fichero2, copié y pegué del editor con el que estaba "jugando".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `fetch`, por ejemplo:

```
fetch("fichero2.html")
  .then(response => {
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(data => {
    document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = data;
  });
```

Aquí se asume que `fichero2.html` está en la misma carpeta que el archivo actual. De estar en otra carpeta debes poner la ruta correcta.

Comment: Muchas gracias !